# uniqueEmail attribute gives error while updating in sails.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I'm creating a sails app I've implemented uniqueEmail property from [How do I handle a Unique Field in sails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868420/how-do-i-handle-a-unique-field-in-sails) it's working fine and throwing the error when Creating model.But the problem is it's throwing following error when updating the model:

```
• email
• "uniqueEmail" validation rule failed for input: 'Raja@gmail.com'
```

How can I resolve it. How to use 'unique' in sails?

Please Help.

Any help would be appreciated.